# Cannot use addEventListener with for in loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the for...in loop to add the event listener to the button because I don't want to repeat myself in case there are many buttons/elements. But it gives me an error of `key.addEventListener is not a function`. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
const firstBtn = document.querySelector('.first-btn');
const secondBtn = document.querySelector('.second-btn');
const data = { firstBtn:'apple', secondBtn:'orange' };

for(const key in data) {
  key.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(data[key]);
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="first-btn">First</button>
<button class="second-btn">Second</button>
```

Comment: `key` is a string, not a DOM element that you can add a listener to.

Comment: @Barmar I see, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Just want to know where to begin the explanation.  Why do *you* think `key.addEventListener` is not a function?  I mean, if it were me, the next natural question would be "what is `key` then?"  Upon inspection it is either going to be the string `firstBtn` or `secondBtn` because those are the properties of `data`. -- neither of those strings have an `addEventListener` property, so `key.addEventListener` will be `undefined`, which, sure enough, is not a function.  You were expecting DOM element objects but you've got strings.  Do you understand this much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key` is the string key of the object, not the DOM element in the variable with the same name.

Put the DOM elements in the object as well.

```js
const firstBtn = document.querySelector('.first-btn');
const secondBtn = document.querySelector('.second-btn');
const data = [{
    el: firstBtn,
    msg: 'apple'
  },
  {
    el: secondBtn,
    msg: 'orange'
  }
];

for (const obj of data) {
  obj.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(obj.msg);
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="first-btn">First</button>
<button class="second-btn">Second</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `document.querySelectorAll('button');` this statment selects all buttons  from DOM.
- `buttons.forEach` `foreach`  loop through all the buttons and add click event it's easier and readable.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(btn);
  });
})
```

```html
<button class="first-btn">First</button>
<button class="second-btn">Second</button>
```